# Table columns overlapping with table-layout fixed

Tags: fixed, overlap, tablelayout

I'm having a bit of a problem with my table columns overlapping when the table has 'table-layout: fixed' CSS property set to it.

The column on the left is responsive, with a min-width set. The column on the right has its width fixed, and is floated right. When the browser is resized, the right column begins to overlap the left column, ignoring its min-width.

When I take away 'table-layout: fixed' (so it defaults to auto), this doesn't happen. But this is undesirable because in older browsers like IE7 the page doesn't render very well, unlike IE8 and more modern browsers.

I've setup a basic example (very stripped down) to demonstrate the issue. Take a look at the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/hGzQu/

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `col` element along with `table-layout:fixed` to avoid complications with `float` and `min-width`:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="0*"><!--min-width equivalent-->
    <col width="30"><!--fixed width column-->
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does "width=0*" mean?

Comment: It means the [width is responsive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#column-width). It is equivalent to min-width.